# Sending Email to a specific address without requiring user to specify their mail server details

Tags: c#, windows, email

Can anyone recommend a simple and reliable method of sending email notifications and possibly log files attachments from a C# program without requiring the installer or the user to configure the program by specifying server details and email addresses etc.
(Mainly because they won't know the details, but also because they could change)

The program will normally be run as a service of a Windows Server, but can be run on a client.

I tried connecting to our own mail server and sending a email to myself, but some ISP's are blocking Port 25 on all servers but their own, so that method isn't working reliably.

Tried sending email through gmail but that was less successful as the port they used was blocked by firewalls. Ditto webservices connecting on weird ports.

Trying to use the local smptservice but did not work either.

It would be nice, but not essential if it was not dependant on my own Internet connection/Servers. (Don't mind them being delayed, but prefer them not to get lost).

Are there any webservices on http/https that allow you to do this sort of thing?

TIA

Comment: I highly doubt there's a real "methods" to this. You can easily try a guessing game - if your e-mail address is tom@abc.com, there's a good chance the outgoing mail server will be smtp.abc.com or mail.abc.com (and maybe a few more) and you can just try with those. I don't think there's any way to deal with authentication or other aspects, though - guess you'll still have to ask your customers :-(

Comment: I know the 'to' email address (since they are going to me) and I know what my email server is, but that doesn't help as I can't always access it.

Comment: don't use email, use http post. create a page or handler on your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May have discovered the solution.

Was catching up on my blog reading over the weekend and came across a recent entry on [Coding Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html) and the very first comment mentions [PostMarkApp](http://postmarkapp.com) which seems to do everything I need (and almost everything I want, apart from attachments which they are considering).

Answer (score 0):

try using cdosys

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310212

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20030316.asp

Comment: AFAIK with cdosys you obviously have to specify the smtp server.

Comment: Uses the local smtp server. If you really want the code to rely on nothing, then telnet into the receiving mail service and probably get send direct to smap. but no, you do not "have" to specify a server, if you read the link, you can see what is required.

Comment: Using the local smtp server does not work. A lot of firewalls are configured to block outgoing mail from all computers, except from the official mail server. 
Also I can't always telnet into the receiving mail service, as some ISPs only allow 25 to their mailserver.